# Line direction histogram plugin vector identification?

Tags: qgis

I was wondering if there is a way of identfying which vector ids fall into a bin. Is this possible to find out? If there isnt is there another plugin that allows you to identify what the angle in a similar fashion as the line histogram. I have used this plugin as a visual aid but do require to know which vectors fall into i.e. 0-11.25 degrees for stats purposes

Below if the line direction histogram and the CSV file that accompanies it..... I want to identify which vectors go in which bin for example the first line on the csv file gives you the sum length and the number of trails in that bin. But I want to identify which vector falls in a bin to carry out statistical analysis
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what angle you're talking about. Can you add an illustration?

Comment: If you just want to know the orientation of a line, you can use the `line_interpolate_angle` function to add a new field with the orientation "in degrees clockwise from north."

Answer (score 1):

The line direction histogram plugin does not operate on complete lines, it operates on the line segments (a line can be made up of hundreds or even thousands of segments). So there is no way to associate lines to direction bins.
See the plugin help for more details on the plugin. About functionality:

`The QGIS Line Direction Histogram Plugin creates a rose diagram that can be used to investigate the distribution of the directions of line segments of a line or polygon vector dataset`